# How to make golang not confuse vendor import with absolute import?

Tags: go, terraform, alibaba-cloud

I dont understand what the error means but I think it is getting confused between the package in absolute path and in the vendor path. How do I make it not confused?

```sh
# github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer/providers/alicloud
providers/alicloud/dum.go:10:35: cannot use func literal (type func(*"github.com/aliyun/aliyun-oss-go-sdk/oss".Client) (interface {}, error)) as type func(*"github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-alicloud/vendor/github.com/aliyun/aliyun-oss-go-sdk/oss".Client) (interface {}, error) in argument to client.WithOssClient
```

Here is the minimum reproducible code

```golang
package dum

import (
    oss "github.com/aliyun/aliyun-oss-go-sdk/oss"
    "github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-alicloud/alicloud/connectivity"
)

func dum() error {
    client := connectivity.AliyunClient{}
    raw, err := client.WithOssClient(func(ossClient *oss.Client) (interface{}, error) {
        return ossClient.ListBuckets()
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    println(raw)

    return nil
}
```

EDIT: Solution

```sh
go mod vendor
go build -v
```

Comment: The error means that the two types, although equivalent, because they live in separate packages, are treated as different. To make the code work, you can either import `oss` from the `github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-alicloud/vendor/....` path. Or have *your* app vendor both `connectivity` and `oss`.

Comment: @mkopriva that seems like it would be good enough for an answer if you want to post it and flesh it out with a reference to documentation about this.

Comment: @mkopriva Vendoring both worked. `go mod vendor` `go build -v`
Can you add this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the two types, although equivalent, because they live in separate packages, are treated as different. To make the code work, you can either import `oss` from the `github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-alicloud/vendor/...` path. Or have your app vendor both `connectivity` and `oss`.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler cannot replace *"github.com/aliyun/aliyun-oss-go-sdk/oss".Client* with *github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-alicloud/vendor/github.com/aliyun/aliyun-oss-go-sdk/oss".Client*, even they have the same name(but from different package).